# If I include asset images from my PC in my flutter app and publish it on the Play Store, will the images appear in the app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have included images from my PC instead of web images, do I need to use web images instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You can include images from your PC too! But make sure you maintain a proper `assets` folder and update in `pubspec.yaml` such that you can use it in your app.

Refer: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: But how my published app can have the images since they are stored on my PC?

Comment: If you follow the above step, when building the apk, the images will be bundled in the apk so that the app can use it. You are placing all your images in `assets` folder which will be within your project.

Comment: Finally my doubt is solved! Thank you so much. I decided to use the local images since the web images were too  slow to load on the app.....

Comment: Happy Coding! :)

Comment: One more doubt, is this a correct way to return images in the if statement?( I have different images for different conditions):

`if (condition < 300) {
      return Image.asset('asset/images/group200.png');
    } `